What’s the accepted variation in a 100 metre track?
How precisely close to 100 metres does a 100 metre track have to be? For example, is it to the nearest millimetre, or the nearest centimetre?
If it matters, assume it’s for the Olympics.

The World Athletics Track and Field Facilities Manual (edition 2019, available here in the "Manuals & Guidelines" section) states:

2.1.1.1 Track Events
The Competition area for Track Events includes:

Oval track with at least 4 lanes (400m + 0.04m × 1.22m ± 0.01m) and safety
zones measuring not less than 1.00m on the inside and preferably at least
1.00m on the outside.

Straight with at least 6 lanes (100m + 0.02m × 1.22m ± 0.01m for sprints and
110m + 0.02m × 1.22m ± 0.01m for hurdles).
Starting area: 3m min. (for 110m Hurdles, Construction Category V: 2.5m min.).
Run-out: 17m min.

Steeplechase track as for oval track with a permanent water jump (3.66m ×
3.66m × 0.50m ±0.05m) placed inside or outside the second bend.



There we can read that the 100m track cannot be shorter than 100m and it can be up to 2 cm longer.
